# Is it possible to leave a bicycle for the day at Karlsplatz, Vienna?

Tags: bicycles, vienna

Karlsplatz is one of the best-connected public transport hubs in Vienna. Is there provision for leaving a bicycle securely there whilst I travel for the day on public transport (U-Bahn, tram, etc) and then return in the evening? I might be doing this regularly.

Comment: Is your question whether or not there is a staffed/guarded bicycle storage place?  If so, please clarify.  If not, the question is rather subjective, as it all depends on the bike, the locks, and the level of risk you are willing to accept (or insure against).

Comment: Well, I think there are some objective measures of security and convenience that are relevant here: ideally I would like a well lit, over-looked region with many cycle stands where I can lock the frame and wheels of my bicycle to a permanent, fixed structure. I'm not expecting armed guards, but I am hoping for more than a lamppost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Google Street View for Karlsplatz, so we can't use it to find bikes parking (it's not a very comprehensive method of finding bike parking, anyway)

Instead, I found this: https://www.wien.gv.at/verkehr/radfahren/stadtplan.html

If you go to the second section, labeled "Radabstellanlagen", you will see a map that lists all kinds of bike facilities around the city including bike racks.

Finally, here are more tips about parking a bike safely:
http://www.argus.or.at/info/rad-und-abstellanlagen/fahrradabstellanlagen-wichtiges-element-radverkehrsfoerderung

Comment: Well spotted! :)

Comment: yeah it looked far too familiar to me for it to be in Wien...I live in Munich ;)